# Joomla Module Class Suffix on th RSS Feed Module

Tags: css, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-module

Im using Joomla 2.5 and I am trying to add a custom module class suffix on the "RSS Feed Display Module" for it to have these values, but only that module not all of them:

```
    .module-content p:last-child {
margin-top: -5px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
}

body.font-size-is-large {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.75em;
}
```

I edited this code in firebug and it works well but im confused on how to add it on Joomla. 
I tried adding the blank before the module class suffix in the advanced options in the joomla module but I cant get the results to show. I have read the Joomla documentation on Module Class Suffix, saw also videos on youtube regarding it, but I cant understand how it works as I am new in Joomla/CSS.

Any help is greatly appreciated, Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean Mr.Alien? I dont know what a DOM is, what I am trying to achieve is to have the css posted added in the RSS Module using the module class suffix. I dont know how to add the css together and to make it work only for that module.

Comment: In other words we will need your markup, also specificity can be an issue here so you can't say, it's vague

Comment: How can I get the markup, I am using the template http://cloudbase2demo17.cloudaccess.net/ I dont know if it helps :/

Comment: When you add the module class suffix in the advanced options, when you preview the site, does it show if you inspect the element?

Comment: It sounds like the module class suffix is not being added to the module class in this case. There may be a problem with the module template. Are you using an override?

Comment: I tried many hours to figure what was the problem, I am not sure if this is it or not. I was trying to have a module class suffix for properties on gantry.css AND for template.css. I tried to edit just the template.css instead of both and now it seems to be working. 
Am I doing it right? Should I add a blank space before typing the class suffix in the module advanced properties or not? Some tutorials say yes others no and I am confused.